# Ask YouTube to delete video asap

Tags: youtube

Some friend of mine was "cat-fished", and long story short - his, nude including, video ended up on YouTube. This person is now blackmailing my friend for lots of money, and for obvious reasons I want this video to be deleted as soon as possible.

I've reported this video. But I'm wondering, whether there any other way ways to get information about this blackmailing user for the police.

Comment: Ask to Police to trace the IP address of video uploader. That is quick and simple for police.

Comment: What's your actual question here? Are you asking how to find info on the person who posted it, or how to get the video taken down asap? I recommend editing your question to clarify, as "how do I find info on the person" is a legal / law enforcement question.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the police to subpoena YouTube (Google) for the uploaders information, Google is highly compliant with these requests.